# Convert variant from recordset (with currency value) into properly formatted string

Tags: c++, ms-access-2007, ado, currency

I have a query that gets the value of the payed amount of money. This field is `currency` type, in MS Access database.

I need to display this value in textbox ( I am using C++ and raw WinAPI for GUI ), so I need to know how to convert `_variant_` from recordset into proper string (`1,200.55`).

Here is an example ( remember, I use raw WinAPI and C++ for GUI ):

```
SetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_EDIT11, 
    pRS->Fields->GetItem(L"PaidValue")->Value.bstrVal); // problem is this line
```

My textbox is empty when I run the program.

When I debug it, it reports no errors.

### QUESTION:

How can I convert `_variant_t` into string ( `1,200.00`)?

Comment: 1. Save to a `variant_t vValue;` 2. `vValue.ChangeType(VT_BSTR);` 3. `SetDlgItemTextW(hDlg, IDC_EDIT1, V_BSTR(&vValue));`. There is an extended variant change type for locale-aware conversions, [`VariantChangeTypeEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221634(v=vs.85).aspx), if you really need it. Worth looking in to.

Comment: @WhozCraig: OK, I have gone through steps and it works. I had to change the last parameter of `SetDlgItemText` to `(VT_BSTR)(&vValue)` in order to work (did you make a typo or I did something wrong?). My problem is that string is not formatted. I get `1200.55` instead of `1,200.55` as a result. As for  `VariantChangeTypeEx`, I was not able to test it. I have `wchar_t temp[50] = L""`, and simply was not able to figure out how to convert this to `BSTR`, since this must be the last parameter. Can you help? Thank you for helping me so far.

Comment: No way that should even compile if that is how you changed the last parameter. It should be `V_BSTR(&vValue)`. The macro `V_BSTR` peels out the `bstrVal` member of the variant. the missing `T` is intentional, as was the `W` at the end of `SetDlgItemTextW`.

Comment: @WhozCraig: OK, I will try again. I am trying out multiple approaches so maybe I got confused. I will try again and report my results. Again, will this group digits using thousands separator, knowing that this is data format I set for the currency in database?

Comment: @WhozCraig: OK, It works -> my mistake. Sorry, I am working hard to solve this on my own... It does not group digits with thousands separator though... That feature is very important to me -> back to the drawing board :)

Comment: No, it will use the default C locale. To get the locale-aware currency separator you're going to have to peel back the onion and configure an appropriate call to com's VariantChangeTypeEx. I suspect you'll using the current thread locale btw, obtainable via [`GetThreadLocale()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318127(v=vs.85).aspx). It would be something like `VariantChangeTypeEx(&vValue, &vValue, GetThreadLocale(), 0, VT_BSTR);`, then use the extraction macro as we discussed before. Its been *forever* since I've done this, but that sounds correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
CString GetString(_variant_t vValue)
{
    USES_CONVERSION;
    CString strValue("");
    if ((V_VT(&vValue) == VT_NULL) || (V_VT(&vValue) == VT_EMPTY))
        return strValue;

    if ((V_VT(&vValue) == VT_BSTR) || SUCCEEDED(VariantChangeType(&vValue, &vValue, 0, VT_BSTR)))
        strValue = OLE2T(V_BSTR(&vValue));

    return strValue;
}

CString strVal = GetString(pRS->Fields->Item["PaidValue"]->Value)
```

Comment: Code-Only answers are not from high value. Please provide a description why your code solves the problem.